# "Projects Presentation" in Package Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

I use Eclipse Oxygen, and recently discovered the hierarchical view of projects in the Project Explorer.

Unfortunately, I am using the Package Explorer.

1. Has the Package Explorer a similar feature?
2. Is the Package Explorer still the first choice for Java development?

Comment: 1. No, Package Explorer doesn't support this. 2. Opinion based.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you. And I would be very glad to hear your opinion on no. 2.

Comment: I use Package Explorer but that is just because I always have.

Comment: @greg-449: Yours should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely: hit the triangle icon on top of it, and go to Package Presentation, then hit Hierarchical, and there you go.

FYI, it's the one and only explorer I use every day

[image]

For the 'working set' part:

Create for instance 2 working sets, 1 with your entry point, another with you sub-modules like so:

[image]

Then change the 'Top Level Elements' value to 'Working set ' like so:

[image]

Hope this time I understood you properly

Comment: I am talking about "Projects Presentation", not "Package Presentation". Thank you for your effort, but I am searching for something different.

Comment: Isn't it the whole point of the package explorer, to present the hierarchy of the packages? I can't seem to understand what you're missing...

Comment: The "Projects Presentation" feature in the Project explorer allows you to hierarchically group your _projects_ (like multi-module projects). I am looking for a similar feature in the package explorer. I am _not_ looking for a hierarchical _package_ view.

Comment: The other leverage you have, and it might be the missing thing for you, are the working sets. When you have a maven projects, it allows you to have a working set for the entry point (useless, unless you want to perform a global operation like team synchronizing), and the 'real' projects your sources point to.

Comment: This means that I manually order my projects into projects and subprojects, not automatically using Maven module structure?

Comment: I'm afraid so, unless there's something I don't know here. Usually you do this once and for all when you import your maven projects, there's a 'Add to working set' feature. Do you have that many projects that it would bother you?

Comment: Thanks for your time. We publish recommendations for 100+ developers in our company, and I want to recommend something that is handy and not much manual work.

Comment: Well then, unless somebody knows a feature I don't, I'm afraid there's not much choice, unless of course, you can publish the working sets for everybody (it's part of the workspace's metadata). Sorry...